# Importing projects into eclipse only imports Android projects

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

When I try to import from eclipse,and select root directory -> select the folder where I have all the my-gdx-game-android,html,desktop.. It only imports the android and it shows a message:

> Could not set the project description for 'my-gdx-game-android'
>   because the project description file (.project) is out of sync with
>   the file system.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure when you import your projects that you select **Existing Projects into Workspace** and not **Existing Android Code into Workspace**.

If you select the second one, Eclipse will only import Android specific projects. The base project in libgdx is a pure Java project that doesn't rely specifically on Android so it won't be imported using that function.  This is also true for your html and desktop projects since they're not Android projects.

Comment: There is only Existing Android CODE Into Workspace!

Comment: Existing Android Code into Workspace shows up under the Android tab. The Existing Projects into Workspace option shows up under the general tab, which should be the first one.